# How to save the content of one variable in another with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have this variable

```
  - debug:
      var: hostvars{{ls_ip}}.host_name
```

The output is:

```
ok: [40.53.52.135] => {
    "hostvars['40.53.52.136'].host_name": "SRV0026"
}
```

I need save the string **SRV0026** in a new var to use this variable in another task, but using set_fact show the var name but not the content. I tried with "var" and "msg"

```
  - set_fact:
      ls_name: hostvars{{ls_ip}}.host_name

  - name: Debug ls_name whit var
    debug:
      var: ls_name

  - name: Debug ls_name whit msg
    debug:
      msg: "{{ls_name}}"
```

The output is:

```
TASK [elasticsearch : Debug ls_name con var] ************************************************************
Tuesday 10 March 2020  15:02:24 -0300 (0:00:00.152)       0:00:04.630 ********* 
ok: [40.53.52.135] => {
    "ls_name": "hostvars['40.53.52.136'].host_name"
}

TASK [elasticsearch : Debug ls_name whit msg] ***********************************************************
Tuesday 10 March 2020  15:02:24 -0300 (0:00:00.098)       0:00:04.729 ********* 
ok: [40.53.52.135] => {
    "msg": "hostvars['40.53.52.136'].host_name"
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I only see the string SRV0026 using debug with var"*

A: To display the value of the variable with debug/msg try this

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[ls_ip].host_name }}"
```

To declare the variable try this

```
  - set_fact:
      ls_name: "{{ hostvars[ls_ip].host_name }}"
```

Comment: Thanks @vladimir-botka, Ansible said:

FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object has no element ['40.53.52.136']\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/github/respaldo_productos/ecomart/roles/elasticsearch/tasks/get-logstash-objects.yml': line 3, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - set_fact:\n    ^ here\n"}

Comment: This is in contradiction with what you claim in the question: `ok: [40.53.52.135] => {"hostvars['40.53.52.136'].host_name": "SRV0026"}`.

Comment: Believe me, I am the first interested in resolving this issue
Ansible is not wrong, something we are not looking at

Comment: I believe you .

Comment: I only see the string SRV0026 using debug with var, I cannot show this content with jinja2 syntax {{ }} with "debug" and "msg"